# How can I setup the line Integral for given problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

> How should I evaluate this  line Integral :
>   $$ \int_{C} (y^2 + z^2)dx + (z^2 + x^2)dy  +  (x^2 + y^2)dz$$ 
>   where $C$ is the part for which $z \ge 0$ of the intersection of the surfaces $x^2 + y^2+ z^2 = 4x$, $x^2+ y^2 = 2x$ and the curve begins at origin and runs at first in the positive octant.

My main Problem Is I am not able to visualize how the curve is formed due to which neither I can define the parametric coordinates nor I can setup the integral properly.

Can anyone tell me how should I solve this problem ?

Comment: Try completing the square to understand what the shapes are (extra hint: just $x^2+y^2 = k$ with two variables instead of three is not the equation of a circle in 3D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.  The curve is the intersection of the sphere $(x-2)^2+y^2+z^2=2^2$ and the cylinder $(x-1)^2+y^2=1^2$ contained in the half-space $z\geq 0$.

Let $x(t)=1+\cos(t)$, and $y(t)=-\sin(t)$ with $t\in [-\pi,\pi]$. Then $(x-1)^2+y^2=1^2$ is satisfied.

Now are you able to find $z(t)$ and write the intersection curve $t\to (x(t),y(t),z(t))$ in a parametric form?

Comment: So, i  get $z^2  = 2x$ and using coordinates of $x$ I can define the parametric coordinates for $z$.                                                                                                                 I have just one more doubt: while calculating the range of $t$ Can I use $t \in [0,2\pi]$  or is there any special significance behind using $t \in [-pi, pi]$ ?                                                                                                 Can you please answer this doubt  ?      Thank you.

Comment: 1)  $z$ is the positive square-root of $2x$ (see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Half-AngleFormulas.html) and 
2) we start from $-\pi$ because "the curve begins at origin and runs at first in the positive octant".